# How to enable Strict Transport Security (HSTS) in angular

Tags: angular

I want to enable HSTS for my Angular 7 website. I am using "ng serve" to host the website.

How do I configure the site to add a HSTS header to the responses?

```
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains
```

Comment: [ng serve uses webpack-dev-server which is a development server and not suited for production.](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/5274#issuecomment-284719639). In short no need to try to add this as it should not be used in a production environment and it does not (really) matter if it is not included in development.

Comment: @Igor Does the choice of server change the Angular answer? How **do** you do it in Angular?

Comment: @IanBoyd - HSTS headers are issued by the web server in the response, not the client/angular in the request. As `ng serve` is not meant to be used as a production web server there are no options to configure response headers to be included from that web server. So the answer to how do you do it in angular is you don't. You do it on the web server.

Comment: Directly related feature request for `ng serve`: [Configure custom HTTP headers](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/6262)

Comment: @Igor Headers *can* be included as page directives. But if he wants to **test** the behavior of HSTS, how does he **test** it in a **test** system?

Comment: @IanBoyd - deploy to any web server that does support adding this header, or adding custom headers, and serving over https. Recommending a web server for testing purposes (or production for that matter) is outside the scope of the question but also [so] IMHO.

Comment: @Igor So the answer to the question is *"Cannot be done?"* Then answer it. Answer the question [simply and directly](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/371355/12597) . Don't down-vote, criticize, and vote to close. Answer the question.

Comment: @IanBoyd - you make too many assumptions. I did not downvote and also I did not close vote. I also didn't criticize the question. I also did not feel that my comment was worthy of being an answer without additional references which I did not have time to procure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The HSTS is requested first by the webserver.
If the webserver is sending you the HSTS header, you have to respond with the HSTS settings.

[Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Strict-Transport-Security) is the details about HSTS.
And [here](https://angular.io/guide/http#http-headers), how to modify HTTP header in angular.